# ¿Como doy formato tipo fecha de un return json dentro de una tabla?

Tags: c#, mvc

Cuando genero un json me lo manda los datos la vista correctamente, sin embargo, la fecha me la coloca como 
/Date(1547013600000)/  pero en el return json me aparece bien 
{[fecha, 09/01/2019 12:00:00 a. m.]}

cuando regresa a mi vista en el data hago un for para agregar los rows a una tabla, es ahi donde no he podido modificar el formato a fecha.

Espero me puedan apoyar..

Controlador

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;

                foreach (DataRow dr in DTResult.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in DTResult.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return Json(rows);
            }
```

vista

```
 success:

                        function (data) {

                            tabla += "<thead><tr><th>Cliente</th><th>Razón Social</th><th>No. Factura</th><th>Fecha</th></th></thead><tbody>";


                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                tabla += "<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].cliente
                                    + "</td>" + "<td>"
                                    + data[i].razon
                                    + "</td>" + "<td>"
                                    + data[i].fact
                                    + "</td>" + "<td>"
                                    + data[i].fecha
                                    + "</td><td>"
                                    + "</td>"
                            }
```

Comment: Estás usando JQuery?

Comment: Asi es uso jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Podrías formatear tu fecha con **[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)** si estas utilizando `JQuery`, de esta manera

```js
console.log(moment('/Date(1547013600000)/').format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

De esta forma puedes manejar el formato que desees y tener acceso a **[más](https://momentjs.com/docs/)** funciones relacionadas con fechas

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una función donde le pasas el valor de tu respuesta.

```
function JsonDate(jsonDate) {
  var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
  return date ;
}
```

La función substr () saca la parte los 6 primeros numeros la función parseInt () obtiene el entero,al final. El número resultante se pasa al constructor Fecha.

tu código quedaría algo así.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   tabla += "<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].cliente
      + "</td>" + "<td>"
      + data[i].razon
      + "</td>" + "<td>"
      + data[i].fact
      + "</td>" + "<td>"
      + JsonDate(Date(data[i].fecha))
      + "</td><td>"
}
```

Enlace donde tiene un pregunta parecida en stackoverflow en ingles [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date#comment19286516_2316066)

saludos

Comment: Utilice esta funcion, sin embargo cuando envia los datos me aparece como undifined